# Can I find similar entries and group them together?

Tags: python, ruby, algorithm, distance, levenshtein-distance

I have a file that contains user inputs in this format:

- Book titles that users are searching for, Number of times that entry was searched

Examples:

- A Wrinkle in Time, 100
- The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn, 100
- Wrinkle in Time, 20
- Peter Pan, 100
- rinkle in time, 5
- Huckleberry Finn, 100
- Adventures of Huckleberry Finn, 150
- Time wrinkle, 2

The book title comes with variations: misspellings, incorrect wording, incorrect order, or slightly different naming. Because of them, the titles won't be all grouped together when the list is sorted A->Z by title:

- A Wrinkle in Time, 100
- Wrinkle in Time, 20
- rinkle in time, 5
- Time wrinkle, 2
- Peter Pan, 100
- The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn, 100
- Huckleberry Finn, 100
- Adventures of Huckleberry Finn, 150

The `A Wrinkle in Time` titles are grouped together, and the `Huckleberry Finn` ones are in their own group, while each row still retains its original respective numerical input.

Is it possible to re-order based on fuzzy logic (maybe use Levenshtein distance and then group that way) via Python or Ruby? If so, what's a simple/straight-forward method for this? 
The question [Group Similar Entries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802433/group-similar-entries-python) is similar to my situation except that I'm using strings of letters instead of numbers.

Comment: Is there any place you can get a canonical list of _actual, correct_ book titles? Because that would make life much simpler...

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. I'm pretty much just working with the CSV that was exported through the "Search Terms" user behavior section of Google Analytics. The "Search Terms" tool in GA tells me what users put into the search box by by parsing out each entry of my-site.com/search?q= with whatever is after the "search?q=" portion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, we use [FuzzyWuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) There are some good tutorials.  Basically if I were going to do this I would use a recursive function to find matches.

When I started using it I had some problems initially and so I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862313/better-way-to-implement-a-machine-learning-algorithm-in-python).

It is straight forward enough if you have a set of known items to match things to but my question addresses the case where you initially do not want to limit the input set.

To get started though see [this example](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2012/07/examples-using-pythons-fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching/).

Comment: Thank you! I've been reading up on FuzzyWuzzy and this mixed with the example way of using a list of known-good titles that Hugh Bothwell mentioned gives me a good jumping off point! I'd upvote if I had high enough reputation to!

Comment: Too bad the linked example doesn't exist anymore. That *exactly* is why people should copy examples into the answer. -1

Answer (score 2):

If you can get a list of known-good titles, it would make your life much easier:

```
import csv
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from itertools import groupby

good_titles = [
    "a wrinkle in time",
    "the adventures of huckleberry finn",
    "peter pan"
]
def best_title(title):
    return process.extractOne(title.lower(), choices=good_titles)[0]

def read_csv(fname, header=False, **kwargs):
    with open(fname, "rb") as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            head = next(incsv, None)
        for row in incsv:
            yield row

def main():
    searches = read_csv("search_data.csv", header=True)
    searches = [(best_title(title), int(num), title) for title,num in searches]
    searches.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1], x[2]))

    for key,items in groupby(searches, lambda s:s[0]):
        for bt, num, t in items:
            print("{:40} {:>5}".format(t, num))
        print('')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

produces

```
A Wrinkle in Time                          100
Wrinkle in Time                             20
rinkle in time                               5
Time wrinkle                                 2

Peter Pan                                  100

Adventures of Huckleberry Finn             150
Huckleberry Finn                           100
The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn         100
```

Comment: You should add the score next to each one so that the OP can start 'learning' where the cutoff should be. Also this works a lot better with recuriveness added

Comment: Thank you both of you! After rereading these recommendations and also brainstorming how and where I could get the data I need, I realized I could run a query on my databases and pull a list of known-good titles! I'm going to try this out and come back with my results/questions before closing this thread out.

Again - thanks! You people rock!

Comment: I tried it out (minus the "learning" recursion that @PyNEwbie mentioned) using the "Good-Known Titles" list

I got this: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "show title fuzzy logic grouping.py", line 1594, in <module>
    main()
  File "show title fuzzy logic grouping.py", line 1585, in main
    searches = [(best_title(title), int(num), title) for title,num in searches]
  File "show title fuzzy logic grouping.py", line 1579, in read_csv
    head = next(incsv, None)
_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?